# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role during login in spring security

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Spring boot with JPA hibernate, with spring security.
My project structure is normal. 
I have used 3 @ManytoMany relations in an entity with another 3 entity in a user Entity.
But when I logged in, One on the @ManytoMany relation show me Error

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.Test.persistance.model.AdminMasterModel.sectorList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:509)
```

My project structure is :
[image]

(1)WebApplication

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

(2)WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true , proxyTargetClass = true )
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    TestAuthenticationFailureHandler TestAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    TestUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler TestUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**")
                .antMatchers("/bower_components/**");

    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup","/permitall/**" , "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .successHandler(TestUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureHandler(TestAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")// Config for Logout Page
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/loginpage?logout").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
        CustomRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new CustomRememberMeServices("theKey", userDetailsService, new InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl());
        return rememberMeServices;
    }
}
```

(3) DataBaseConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource( "classpath:database.properties" )
@ComponentScan({ "com.Test.persistance"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.Test.persistance.dao")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUserName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    @Value("${spring.user.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String dbDriver;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 1000);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }

   /* @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.Test.exam.bean.persistance.model");
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }*/

    /*@Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }*/

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(testDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.Test.persistance.model" });
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return em;
    }
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

(4)AdminMasterModel

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_admin_master")
public class AdminMasterModel extends BaseDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String adminEmail;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String adminSectorDetails;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String adminName;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String adminMobile;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "admin_sector",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "sector_id", referencedColumnName = "ssc_id"))
    private Collection<SectorMasterModel> sectorList;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "admin_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> adminRoles;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "admin_job_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "job_id"))
    private Collection<JobRoleModel> jobRoleModels;


}
```

(5)ROLE

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_master")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adminRoles")
    private Collection<AdminMasterModel> admin;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentRoles")
    private Collection<StudentMasterModel> student;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "assessorRoles")
    private Collection<AssessorMasterModel> assessor;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "roles_privileges", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;

    public Role() {
        super();
    }

    public Role(final String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Role role = (Role) obj;
        if (!role.equals(role.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Role [name=").append(name).append("]").append("[id=").append(id).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

(6)SectorMasterModel

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sector_master", schema = DBConstants.EXAM_SCHEMA)
public class SectorMasterModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length = 3)
    private Integer ssc_id;
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String ssc_name;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String short_name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "sectorList" , cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AdminMasterModel> admin;

    private Timestamp created_at;
    private Long created_by;
    private Integer is_active;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SectorMasterModel{" +
                "ssc_id=" + ssc_id +
                ", ssc_name='" + ssc_name + '\'' +
                ", short_name='" + short_name + '\'' +
                ", created_at=" + created_at +
                ", created_by=" + created_by +
                ", is_active=" + is_active +
                '}';
    }
}
```

> I can log in successfully from UI but after login I found this error

```
2019-07-13 22:41:32.432 ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleCommittedResponse:213 - Cannot forward to error page for request [/adminmain/dashboard] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.Test.persistance.model.AdminMasterModel.sectorList, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:509)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.Test.persistance.model.AdminMasterModel.toString(AdminMasterModel.java:15)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.getName(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.getUsernameForRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1092)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You have a Lazy loading of all collections. This exception has place when you try to access data after hibernate session was closed. This exception you would get on all your other relationships.

Comment: You can use @Transactional on a method where you access collection data (this is recommended), or may be with this small data it would help to use Eager type on one of the end, or both - if you will not get to a loop overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is pretty clear: `AdminMasterModel.toString()` tries to access `AdminMasterModel`'s lazy properties after the persistence context has been closed.

To solve this, you need to customize the default `toString()` implementation generated by `@Data` to exclude lazy associations. Try putting `@ToString.Exclude` on `sectorList`, `adminRoles`, and `jobRoleModels`.

Comment: @ToString.Exclude is not defined.

Comment: I have used @ToString(exclude = "sectorList , adminRoles, jobRoleModels") , But it shows this error:
at com.anoman.persistance.model.SectorMasterModel.hashCode(SectorMasterModel.java:15)

Comment: You'll probably want to exclude the fields from `@EqualsAndHashCode` for the very same reason. I suggest de-lomboking the class (leaving perhaps `@Getter`, `@Setter`, and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`) and implementing `toString()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()` yourself to see if the problem goes away. You can then experiment with re-applying Lombok